# Boost Licensing changes

Tags: c++, boost, licensing

I have couple of questions regarding boost licensing,

1. Is it that all the boost libraries have the same "boost licensing" or does it vary for some libraries?
2. Has there been any recent changes in licensing for some boost libraries?

I tried to find information by simple search but could not get any specific information. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Hmm. Being aware of the licensing implications when using libraries is very much on topic when programming or when doing software development. Considering this to be off-topic creates serious problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same [license](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt) for every library in Boost.

Comment: Nope. Although this is the goal, some boost libraries use different licenses.